# MCLocalization Missing Strings

Tags: ios

[image]I have used MCLocalization for localizing strings.

I have added all strings correctly but some of few strings it says there are no strings.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to show sometihing, so that we can try to observce   the problem instead of just putting a statement in the question .

Comment: Solved ..I have localized twice..